# lodash - chaining filter and forEach

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following working code written with lodash, latest version

```
            _.forEach(_.filter($ctrl.data, ['x', 'y']), function (elem) {
                ...
            });
```

If I try to transform this into a chain, it will never execute the block code inside `forEach`.

```
            _.chain($ctrl.data)
                .filter(['x', 'y'])
                .forEach(function (elem) {
                   ...
                });
```

Why?

Comment: if you console.log `_.chain($ctrl.data).filter(['x', 'y'])`, what does it return?

Comment: I debugged using `_.chain($ctrl.data).filter(['x', 'y']).value()` and it returns the filtered array, as expected.

Comment: then you should try `_.chain($ctrl.data).filter(['x', 'y']).value().forEach(function(elem) { .. });`

Comment: This is not ok. It will call `forEach` on javascript `Array` which is not right. My code should be backwards compatile and there are some older browsers which does not support `forEach`.

Comment: _.chain([1,2,3]).forEach(console.log) works as expected, your code should too.

Comment: `.forEach` is ES5: http://caniuse.com/#feat=es5 if you want to support older browsers you can always use a regular for-loop, or consider using a shim.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the problem by using `_($ctrl.data)` instead of `_.chain($ctrl.data)`. I read that the main difference here is that the global function from lodash calls `_.value()` when it has a "terminator function" at the end.

An equivalent using `_.chain` would be to explicitly call `_.value()` at before `_.forEach()`. But still can't figure out what is the problem because, from my point of view, a `forEach` is a "terminator function".

Answer (score 4):

This happens because execution of chained methods in lodash is lazy.

From lodash documentation on sequences:

> The execution of chained methods is lazy, that is, it's deferred until _#value is implicitly or explicitly called.

That means that following code:

```js
_.chain(['a','b','c'])
    .filter(_.stubTrue)
    .forEach(i => console.log(i))
```

will not print anything to console unless the sequence will be ended with `value()`:

```js
_.chain(['a','b','c'])
    .filter(_.stubTrue)
    .forEach(i => console.log(i))
    .value()
a
b
c
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved some of my confusion! However, I also note that there's a difference between using the above and the "point free" form of `console.log`: `_.chain([1, 2, 3]).filter(x => x === 2).each(console.log).value()` which prints "2 0". I guess the documentation for the array-case is just a bit unspecific here. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#forEach. But that's a separate discussion

Comment: It prints `2 0`, because when writing `each(console.log)`, you are sending `console.log` both the item value and its index. From documentation of the `_.each` function: "The iteratee is invoked with three arguments: (value, index|key, collection).". If you want to print only the item value, you have to use `each(i => console.log(i))`.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into a similar issue. I was using the `_(blah)` syntax and I was still running into issues.

In my case, the code looked like this:

```
_(items).forEach((x) => doSomething(x));
```

It turns out the `doSomething` was returning a `boolean`. I guess lodash sees this return value and treats `forEach` the same as `map`, not evaluating it. However, I tried tacking on a `value()` onto the end and I get a `value is not a function` error at runtime.

In my case, the problem was solved by wrapping the `doSomething` call:

```
_(items).forEach((x) => { doSomething(x); });
```

Seems more like a bug than anything.